# Chain of elements of a chain of order ideals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $P$ be a partially ordered set, and let $I(P)$ be the set of order ideals (i.e. downward-closed sets) in $P$ ordered by inclusion. Suppose that $X$ is a chain of non-empty elements of $I(P)$. Claim: there is a monotonic function $f : X \to P$ such that $f(J) \in J$ for each $J \in X$. In other words, the chain of ideals has a corresponding chain of elements. Is this claim true?

**Edit.** To clarify, by "monotonic" I don't mean "strictly monotonic". That is, we just want for $J, K \in X$, if $J \subseteq K$ then $f(J) \leq f(K)$.

Comment: By "ideals in $I(P)$" do you mean "elements of $I(P)$" or do you really mean "ideals in the poset $(I(P),\subseteq)$"?

Comment: By "monotonic" you mean "**strictly** increasing", right? So your monotonic function $f$ must, in particular, be injective?

Comment: Good points. I mean "elements of I(P)". And I really didn't mean "strictly"—I meant if $J \subseteq K$ then $f(J) \leq f(K)$. Sorry that was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample:** Let
$$P=\{(x,y)\in\omega\times\omega:x\ge y\}$$
with the ordering
$$(x',y')\le(x,y)\iff x'=x\wedge y'\le y$$
and let $X=\{J_n:n\in\omega\}$ where
$$J_n=\{(x,y)\in P:x\ge y+n\}.$$

**Simpler example:** Let $P=\omega$ with the trivial ordering
$$x\le y\iff x=y$$
and let $X=\{J_n:n\in\omega\}$ where
$$J_n=\{n,\,n+1,\,n+2,\,n+3,\dots\}.$$

Comment: Those are good answers to an unintended reading—I forgot that "monotonic" was ambiguous. In fact, I think by Generalized Cantor's Theorem, any totally ordered set will be a counterexample to the "strictly" reading. I'm not seeing an obvious way to convert these to answers to the "non-strict" question, though.

Comment: Cool. Should the last line say $x \geq n$? (Also, I think as the question was originally posed I want the dual to this order.)

Comment: Actually, do we need the restriction of $P$ to $y \geq x$? If I'm understanding correctly it seems like this should still work for $P = ω × ω$.

Comment: I meant $x\ge y+n$ but you're right, $x\ge n$ also works, as does $P=\omega\times\omega$. I posted my last answer in a hurry, and didn't have time to clean it up. See how I've edited it now.

Comment: I'm confused about the original example. By the definition of $P$, isn't $J_n$ empty for $n > 0$?

Comment: Also, I think in the simpler example $P$ should be just $\omega$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections. I've corrected the typos in my two definitions of $P$.